# dynamically extend jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

i want to create a flexible jquery plugin for handling forms, here's my markup + code:

```
<div id="myform" validate="1">form</div>

    <script>

        (function ($) {
            $.fn.myForm = function()
            {
                var me = this;
                if(me.attr("validate"))
                {
                    me.validate();
                }
            };

        })(jQuery);

        // code from external file eg. myform_validate.js
        $.fn.myplugin.validate = function () {
            // form validation here
            alert("validate");
        };

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myform').myForm();
        });

    </script>
```

what i want to achieve is somekind of plugin-in-plugin structure which means myForm is the base plugin for each project and if required i would add extra functionality/methods like form validation or an image uploader to the plugin (by loading additional external scripts).
this should be dont without instantiation, directly inside the plugin.
as you might expect, the above code doesn't work .. :/
any ideas if this is possible? 
thanks

Comment: `this` isn't what you think it is. In all `$.fn.someMethod()`  it is the element collection represented by selector which allows `return this` for jQuery method chaining

Comment: This is a very large question since there is not a method better than an other... It also depend what do you want in the end. This is a perfectly valide example (https://jsfiddle.net/jfqatfvz/), but simplified...

Comment: By plugin-in-plugin i think you mean factory. Check out jQuery's [widget factory](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/why-use-the-widget-factory/) for use or inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably numerous ways to achieve expected results. Here, checks if `validate` method from "external file" is defined, if yes, sets `validate` as property of `myForm` ; utilizes `Function.prototype.call` to set `this` within `validate`

```js
(function($) {
  function myForm() {
    me = this;
    if (me.attr("validate")) {
      if (myForm.validate) {
        myForm.validate.call(me)
        .text(me.text() + " validated")
        .css("color", "green");
      }
    };
    return me
  };
  try {
    if (validate && typeof validate === "function") {
      myForm.validate = validate
    } 
    // catch `ReferenceError` if `validate` is not defined
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e.message)
  }

  $.fn.myForm = myForm;

})(jQuery);

// code from external file eg. myform_validate.js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").myForm();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
  // external file
  function validates() {
    // form validation here
    console.log(this)
    alert("validate");
    // `this` : `#myform`
    return this
  };
</script>
<div id="myform" validate="1">form</div>
```